# I Need to Keep a Window Active

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, firefox, autohotkey

I need to keep a browser window active while I use another window.

"Keep-on-Top" is not what I'm looking before because when I switch pages, it still goes inactive.

I'm trying to keep a page from recognizing that I'm leaving the window (about a 10 second window before recognition).

I stumbled across an AutoHotKey but I'm not savvy enough to use it:

```
SetTimer, constantActivation, 10
return
constantActivation:
WinWaitNotActive, your_window
WinActivate, your_window
return
```

Any advice or tips? Right now, I have my mouse set to make a page active just by hovering over, but that's not really going to cut it if I have to hover over the window every 9 seconds.

For example, I'd like to browse in Firefox on the right while keeping Chrome active on the left:
[image]

Comment: "_I need to keep a browser window active while I use another window._" isn't that an oxymoron? The "_active window_" is the one you're interacting with - there can be only one.

Comment: "_I'm trying to keep a page from recognizing that I'm leaving the window_" What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I know it sounds like an oxymoron, but the fun thing about computers is that there's usually a way around something.

Comment: If anything, it's surely a fun challenge.

Comment: One option would be to use a VM... _What exactly are you trying to achieve?_ Why do you need to "_keep Chrome active_"? What happens if you don't?

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but you can give this a try...

```
; Keeping window active while a script is running.

#NoEnv ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
#Persistent ; Keeps a script permanently running until the user closes it or ExitApp is encountered.
#SingleInstance, Force ; Determines whether a script is allowed to run again when it is already running.
DetectHiddenWindows, On ; Determines whether invisible windows are "seen" by the script.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetTitleMatchMode, 2 ; Sets the matching behavior of the WinTitle parameter in commands.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

SetTimer, WinExist_YOUR-WINDOW, 100
WinExist_YOUR-WINDOW:
If WinExist("YOUR-WINDOW ahk_class AutoHotkey")
    WinActivate, ahk_exe YOUR-WINDOW.EXE
Return
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).